# Ionic iOS Selecting the background application after a while, it only shows the splash screen and the application does not continue

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Installing the Ionic application in iOS 11.3 it works correctly after pressing the home menu and the application goes to background after approximately 3 hours
Select the application then only the splash screen is show and don't continue with the application.
I check in safari the navigation and it shows an about:blank, there is nothing in resources and in the console prints

> exception nativeEvalAndFetch: ReferenceError: Can not find variable: cordova.

- iOS: 11.3.1
- engine name = "ios" spec = "4.4.0"
- @ ionic / cli-utils: 1.19.2
- ionic (Ionic CLI): 3.20.0
  global packages:
- Cordova (Cordova CLI): 8.0.0
  local packages:
- @ ionic / app-scripts: 3.1.6
- Cordova Platforms: android 6.4.0
- Ionic Framework: ionic-angular 3.9.2
  System:
- Node: v6.11.5
- npm: 5.6.0

Comment: I've currently checked in the console and it shows the following: `exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova` _global code about:blank 1:127
global code script element 1:1:127_ `try {
    cordova.require('cordova/exec').nativeEvalAndFetch(function() {
        cordova.fireDocumentEvent('active');
    })
} catch (e) {
    console.log('exception nativeEvalAndFetch : ' + e);
}; ` 
Looking for this code in xcode I find that it is in CDVCommandDelegateImpl.m but I could not solve it yet

Comment: Has anyone figured this out yet? Still looks like a problem

Comment: I'm in similar case. App start under Android, but it doesn't works under iOS. Did you have find a solution ?